# Is it possible to see package download stats from Hackage?

Tags: haskell, cabal, hackage

It looks like there are reports released on occasion that detail downloads for some of the top packages (http://haskellwebnews.wordpress.com/2011/03/16/hackage-stats-the-past-year/).

Is it possible to see updated stats for individual packages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only from those posts. The apache logs aren't public.